# What is the best CPH for blue charms?

Tags: runescape

What monster in Runescape allows the greatest CPH (charms per hour) for blue charms? I need the charms for a huge summoning run for steel minotaurs. Answers must give CPH and should include locations for the monsters.

For a calculator here's a site to go to. [Charm calculator](http://www.zybez.net/guides/10301/charms_calculator/)

I'm currently using full bandos and can use terror birds. I use sharks as food and can also bring prayer potions.

Comment: What, exactly, does CPH stand for? I'm at a loss here...

Comment: @Unionhawk CPH is Charms per hour. It's calculated by a level 150 attacking the monster and finding his charms per hour then adding 5 and subtracting 5 to get the range.

Comment: How can we give the CPH if you're the level 150 here? We can give you monsters to kill, but CPH is entirely up to you to determine, sorry

Comment: Where is this standard CPH defined?  Is there a reference for it somewhere?  Perhaps including a link to it might come in handy, as it doesn't seem people understand what you're talking about.

Comment: As per the link you gave, the statistics are purely based on user submissions. There seem to be no clear cut values on it and the best approximation *is* said link. Which, therefore, means you are asking us to go through every item in that drop down and find the maximum value, essentially.

Comment: Still unclear how we're supposed to calculate this. The calculator gives charms-per-kill, but we actually need charms-per-hour. To calculate CPH we need both charms-per-kill *and* kills-per-hour. How are we supposed to calculate kills-per-hour for the level 150?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The user submission is for the level 150. That's done. Put in the monster and the amount of monsters you can kill in an hour. Boom CPH.

Comment: Right, exactly. We don't know how many monsters of each type you or the standard level 150 can kill in an hour. How can we calculate CPH without knowing that? I see that killing 200 cows nets 1 blue charm. How many cows can a level 150 kill in an hour?

Comment: That calculator is most likely out of date (with EoC and all).

Comment: @YoungGuilo - I've already voted to reopen your question, because it is not unclear what you are asking, but if you are open to some advice, I think it could be asked better.  Determining the fastest way for your character to obtain blue charms requires that we know about your character - combat levels, equipment and so on.  If you were to revise your question to include that information, it would greatly help those that are able to answer the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is impossible for anyone else to calculate CPH for you since only you have access to your account. You must determine CPH yourself by:

1. Killing the monsters for 10 minutes.
2. With the amount of charms you have, multiply it by 6 (10 minutes * 6 is an hour).
3. That is an approximate CPH rate.
4. Repeat the test for statistically stronger results.

---

A good monster to kill (at your level) is the [Wallasalki](https://runescape.wikia/w/Wallasalki) located in the [Waterbirth Island Dungeon](https://runescape.wikia/w/Waterbirth_Dungeon).

To get to the dungeon, you can do either the following:

1. Teleport to Waterbirth Island with the Lunar Magics Spellbook (after Lunar Diplomacy quest)
2. Talk to Jarvald at the Relekka Docks.

No quests are required to go to Waterbirth Island (and thus the dungeon), but the boat will cost 1,000 gp if The Fremennik Trials has not been completed.

After arriving at the island, go counter clockwise and you will eventualy see a dungeon entrance. There will be lots of aggressive dagannoths at the entrance, so be careful.

There are wallasalkis around the dungeon. A map of where they the monster is located can be found [here](https://runescape.wikia/w/Map:Waterbirth_Island_Dungeon). According to the unofficial wiki, they have a 12% chance of dropping a blue charm.

---

Also, every day, you can kill [Bork](https://runescape.wikia/w/Bork) (after completing The Hunt for Surok miniquest). He will always drop 5 blue charms, or 10 if you have completed all of the Varrock Tasks.

---

I'd like to point out that using blue charms at a low level is not a very good idea. You should keep your blue charms in the future when you have a very high summoning level, and that obtaining blue charms is more common and has a better use. At your level, you should stick to gold and green charms (or maybe even crimsons) to level up.

Comment: 1) My account is a level 186. 2) CPH has a standard of a level 150. 3) I didn't ask whether or not I should use blue charms. 4) calculate CPH.

Comment: @YoungGuilo You know nothing about CPH.

Comment: Enlighten me please.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I have told you. Kill the monsters for 10 minutes. With the amount of charms you have, multiply it by 6 (10 * 6 is an hour). That is an approximate CPH rate. Repeat the test for stronger results

Comment: I've edited your clarifying comment into the answer, and moved the central point (that CPH must be calculated personally) to the top in order to emphasise it. Feel free to revert all or part of that if you don't like the way it changes your answer!

Comment: Look at Alex's answer.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I'm not sure how that helps with what you're asking at all.  He's just given you numbers, without a source, and you've gone ahead and accepted it.  This feels more like revenge voting than providing an actual, useful answer.  Granted, if it's helpful to you, that's fine.  But I don't know how that meshes with what you're asking.

Comment: @fbueckert instead of wasting precious time at walli's I can fight tormented demons with a better CPH.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I assumed you were low levelled (steel minotaurs), so I did not mention Tormented Demons. TDs are also much more dangerous